# Using "easily" at the beginning or middle of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Grammatically, is there a difference between how things are worded in the following two sentences?

```
Easily create your own games with GameMaker 2000.
```

or

```
Create your own games easily with GameMaker 2000.
```

I would prefer the word "create" to be at the beginning because I feel it draws attention to what the sentence is about. However, the word "easily" seems a bit awkward in the middle.

Are both of these sentences grammatically correct? Is there a reason that one would be preferred over the other?

*Disclaimer: GameMaker 2000 is a generic term I am using in place of the actual product name.

Comment: You could rephrase it:  _Create your own games with ease using GameMaker 2000._

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences of the OP are acceptable with a subtle difference in meaning, though.
*Easily* as an adverb of manner will usually go in the end position of a clause, and sometimes in the mid position.
The end position of the clause is  the last item in the clause.

*Create your own games easily.*

*Create your own  games (with...) easily.*

The mid position is between the subject and the main verb.

(*You) Easily create your own games with...*

> Adverbs of manner: They usually go in end position. They sometimes go
>   in mid position if the adverb is not the most important part of the
>   clause or if the object is very long.
>
> *She ate quickly.*
>
> *She quickly ate her dinner and ran out.*

(From [English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position), Cambridge Dictionary)